# Why higher await time for DM multipath device than underlying device?

Tags: performance, iowait, device-mapper

We have a CentOS 6.4 based server attached to Hitachi HNAS 3080 storage and observed the kernel remount the filesystem in read-only mode:

> May 16 07:31:03 GNS3-SRV-CMP-001 kernel: [1259725.675814] EXT3-fs (dm-1): error: remounting filesystem read-only

This happened after several I/O errors and all paths to the device reportedly going down:

> May 16 07:31:03 GNS3-SRV-CMP-001 multipathd: mpatha: remaining active paths: 0

I have been looking at sar logs and can see few very large (2 seconds) await times:

```
07:40:00       dev8-0     17.91    112.04     98.03     11.73      0.00      0.20      0.07      0.12
07:40:00      dev8-16      0.23      1.85      0.00      8.00      0.00      3.71      3.71      0.09
07:40:00      dev8-32     91.50   8338.76   5292.93    148.98      8.38     91.60      9.76     89.35
07:40:00     dev252-0     91.27   8336.91   5292.93    149.34     17.79    194.88      9.79     89.38
07:40:00     dev252-1    674.80   8168.16   5292.93     19.95   1473.53   2183.60      1.32     88.98
```

The duration between 07:30:00-07:40:00 does happen the time when the filesystem got mounted read-only. However, even under normal conditions, one repeated observation is that the await time for underlying devices is much lower than that of the multipath device. For instance:

```
00:00:00          DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
00:10:00       dev8-0     19.27    129.41     78.61     10.80      0.01      0.27      0.16      0.32
00:10:00      dev8-16      0.23      1.80      0.00      8.00      0.00      0.86      0.84      0.02
00:10:00      dev8-32     94.88  10285.16   3363.48    143.86      3.39     35.76      6.83     64.82
00:10:00     dev252-0     94.65  10283.34   3363.48    144.18      3.64     38.47      6.86     64.89
00:10:00     dev252-1    435.06  10087.12   3363.48     30.92    118.42    272.21      1.47     64.12
```

dev8-0 happens to be the local disk, while dev8-16 (`/dev/sdb`) and dev8-32 (`/dev/sdc`) are the underlying ones for dev252-0 (`/dev/mapper/mpatha`). dev252-1 (`/dev/mapper/mpathap1`) is a single partition spanning the whole of the multipath device. Here is output from `multipath -ll`:

```
mpatha (2521501cbffffffffe96773b50ec30020) dm-0 BlueArc,NAS Platform
size=10T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled
| `- 9:0:0:0 sdc 8:32 active ready running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=active
  `- 8:0:0:0 sdb 8:16 active ready running
```

Why should the await time for `/dev/mapper/mpathap1` be so much higher than that of `/dev/mapper/mpatha` or even `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc`?

Comment: It seems noteworthy that apparently a lot of request merging is happening on the way from `/dev/mapper/mpathap1` to  `/dev/mapper/mpatha`. This is also the layer where most of the `await` time seems to be added. Can you check which elevators are used in `/sys/block/mpathap1/queue/scheduler` and `/sys/block/mpatha/queue/scheduler`, possibly switching it to `deadline` or `noop` for comparison?

Comment: The [I/O scheduler](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/008jun05/features/schedulers/) for `mpatha` (`/sys/block/dm-0/queue/scheduler`) is `noop` and that for `mpathap1` (`/sys/block/dm-1/queue/scheduler`) is `none`.

Comment: @the-wabbit, the elevator for underlying devices, `/dev/sd{b,c}` is `cfq`. Is it required to change them to `noop` as well? I will could try to change the elevator for `dm-0` to `deadline` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: you need to check, what happening in your SAN.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the scheduler's queueing/merging algorithm is responsible for the delay. I would swap cfq of the underlying devices for noop or deadline just to see if it changes anything. This likely will be unrelated to your all paths down issue, though.

Comment: Sounds like one of your drives might be going bad.  Are you able to take your system down and run an `fsck` on it? (obviously, do a backup of the SAN/system first)

Comment: How are you using that device? Are you doing LVM or something similar? I have seen this type of behavior when LVM has not been setup to use the multipath device vs. the physical devices.

Comment: anyway I don't see the sense to partition the luns, LUN(LOGICAL UNIT) and why I need to do other partition in my OS side?

Comment: FWIW, I have observed the same kind of behaviour on other types of device mapper devices - specifically with [NSS pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novell_Storage_Services). Merge-able writes do have a higher await (and longer queues) on the `dm` device than on the underlying physical device while read requests and writes without any merging done are mainly unaffected. I do not know yet if this is simply a presentation error due to the way awaits are calculated or actually prolonged response times due to the nature of the queueing / merging algorithm.

Comment: One of the [Systemtap IO scripts](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/keyword-index.html#IO) could possibly provide you with additional insight into what is going on. io_submit.stp, ioblktime.stp, and biolatency-nd.stp might be good places to start.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

As user the-wabbit suggests, there is request-merging going on.
You can see that in the column avgrq-sz, the average request size - which shows a significant increase.

Now 'await' is the time spent in the queue plus the time spent servicing those requests. If a small request, let's call it 'x', is merged with a couple of other requests (y and z, issued after x), then x will

- wait in the queue to be merged with y
- wait in the queue tu be merged with z
- wait for (x,y,z) to be completed

This will obviously have a negative impact on the await statistic, mostly because of the way await is calculated, without actually signifying a problem in itself.

Now let's take a look at /dev/sdb (dev8-16). Did you know that you are not using that path? You have two priority groups in your multipath config, one is

```
status=enabled
```

and on is

```
status=active
```

You probably have

```
path_grouping_policy    failover
```

in your configuration (which is the default).

If you want to prevent the IO errors in case both paths are down, you could try:

```
        features        "1 queue_if_no_path"
```

in your multipath.conf

Now the real question remains, why do both paths go down?